# Error de validacion w3c frameborder recaptcha

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un sitio web creado en wordpress con el plugin de recaptcha para lo de google y evitar spam. Queria saber si hay alguna manera de poner el recaptcha manualmente sin plugin ya que al validar con el validador de w3c me da el siguiente error

```
 The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 196, column 5; to line 196, column 194 
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6Lf6pwgUAAAAAASINHjY19c95ftI3Mf7K8bVg7GI" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;">↩ 

The scrolling attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 196, column 5; to line 196, column 194
<iframe    src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6Lf6pwgUAAAAAASINHjY19c95ftI3Mf7K8bVg7GI" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;">↩
```

Queria saber como puedo corregir estos errores?

Comment: ¿cuál plugin utilizas?

Comment: para crear los formularios el contact form 7 y es la opcion que viene integrado

Answer (score -1):

Si tienes acceso al código html puedes eliminar los parametros `frameborde` y `scrolling` y tu problema se solucionara, el resto queda en agregar lo siguiente en el esilo:

Para reemplazar `frameborde` `style="border:none;"
En el caso de scrolling no es necesario un estilo, tu código quedaría así:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6Lf6pwgUAAAAAASINHjY19c95ftI3Mf7K8bVg7GI" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border: none;">
```

Eso debería solucionar. ;)

Comment: No tengo acceso al codigo ya que utilizo contact form7